# Classic Custom email template Record Detail link

Tags: email-template, hyperlink

```
 <h2>Results of the Completed Request are  attached in the record  </h2>

 <p>  Click the link below  to view the Request record </p>


 Request Link: {!Request__c.Link}
```

When I click the link in the received email, the URL is broken.

How can i create a hyperlinnk to the record detail page in a email template without letter head.

Note: Text Email temmplate works correctly. However I want to format the email, and add rich text that's the reason for the Custom Email template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this time-honored formula expression:

```
LEFT($Api.Partner_Server_URL_550, FIND( ‘/services’, $Api.Partner_Server_URL_550)) & 
{!Request__c.Id}
```