# Building a record detail link URL in a custom Email Template

Tags: email-template, merge-field

I have created a custom email template with Opportunity Fields.

In the Email template, I want to create a link that will open a record.  The recordId of the is auto stored in a text field on the Opportunity via flow.  I am wondering how I could create a URL in the email template to open the Detail Page of the record

**This is the approach I was thinking of -**

1. Create a custom label with the URL of the org.
2. In the email template concatenate the custom label value and the Custom text field value

However this will build the URL as

https://somethingsomething--SB3.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Request__c/aAA6a000000AANaAAa

Instead of

https://somethingsomething--SB3.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Request__c/aAA6a000000AANaAAa/view

How can i append the /view  ?

or is there a way to build a detail record link in the email template?

**Edit 06/25/2022**

Based on suggestion I was able to get the link to work (see screen shot). However I don't want to hard code the URL as this will break when deployed to other environments.

How can I make the URL dynamic so that it will work in all the environments?

[image]

Comment: How is this different from your earlier question?  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/379195/classic-custom-email-template-record-detail-link

Comment: This one is concatenating two strings.  string 1 = https://mydomainname.lightning.force.com, string 2 =  recordid 

Previous question  about detail link  in a custom email template that doesn't show as a url. In the previous questions thDetailLink already has the url and record id. In the new question, I can't use the detail link, I am building the  DetailLink

Comment: You can user link of [org/id] and it will redirect the user to the view url (assuming that the user is lightning mode): https://somethingsomething--SB3.lightning.force.com/aAA6a000000AANaAAa

Comment: Thanks @LironC I was able to get the url to work based on your response. However, I don't want to hard code the org url as this will not work when deployed to other environments. I have edited my question to show progress.

Comment: @GroundToCloud from your original question it seems you managed to solve the orgId with the custom label and the issue was only the '/view' addition. Anyway, saw you already solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

Finally this is how I solved my url issue in the email template

[image]

Comment: interesting solution

Answer (score 0):

To get Base URL just simply use

{!MID(Account.Link, 1, LEN(Account.Link)-15)}

After Base URL apply your Logic as usual.

Comment: do you have the documentation for this?